# prove that If and only if lines are perpendicular, the slopes are negative reciprocal.

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have to prove that If and only if lines are perpendicular, the slopes are negative reciprocal.

I know to prove that if the lines are perpendicular,the slopes are negative reciprocal.
But I dont know how to prove the opposite condition.
Thanks.

Comment: "prove" one "o"

Comment: Are you doing this in the context on linear algebra? Because the converse is shown easily using the dot product

Comment: analytic geometry.

Comment: Use the angle between the lines is given by $$\theta =\tan^{-1} \frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$$, What can you see from this?